# prepareForSegue won't pass data in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass a text from a text field in a view controller to a label in a second view controller via `prepareForSegue`, but it's not working.

My code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    // use of override func prepare gives an error
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var DestViewController: secondViewController = segue.destination as! secondViewController
        DestViewController.labelText = inputTextField.text!
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var receivedTextLabel: UILabel!

    var labelText = "ss"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        receivedTextLabel.text! = labelText
    }
}
```

If I use `override` for `prepareForSegue`, I get the following error:

> Method does not override any method from it's superclass

Without overriding, it builds, but after performing the segue from the button to `SecondViewController`, the label's text doesn't get updated.

Comment: Did you connect your button with any segue action in storyboard? You can remove your action from first ViewController, if in the storyboard you provide correct navigation to 2nd ViewController.

Comment: @VinnyTwice Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title, it's superfluous. See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/364493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method changed back in Swift 3 from `prepareForSegue(segue:sender)` to `prepare(for:sender:)`. Replace it with the following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

Comment: If you stick `override` before a function and Xcode says it doesn't override anything in the superclass try retyping the beginning of the method name on an empty line at the class level. Be sure to skip `override` and `func`. That should get autocomplete to fill in the correct name for you (though you may have to type a fair amount of the name to narrow it down to the right thing), that way you know it's the right version. (If Xcode is doing that thing where it doesn't do autocomplete try quitting and re-launching.)

Comment: @theMikeSwan Good point, but I think this comment would be more appropriate under the question.

Comment: You beat me to it. (voted.) In addition to using auto-complete, you should also try looking up the method name in the Xcode help system. (If you know the Objective-C method name, you can search for that, find it, and then switch to Swift.)

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) did fix the problem. I did try to follow the tip to start typing the just start of the function name but hasn'n shown any autocomplete, not until I commented out the function and then I could access the autocomplete for the function.So that arise another question. Can I have only a prepare (for:segue:sender) function per class? if is it so I should perform all the data passing in it right?

Comment: @VinnyTwice Right. You should handle the different outcomes in one function.

Comment: say that I want to pass the just inputted data to another class and not the default UIStoryboardSegue, the segue: is where I should specify the receiving class or that stays default UIStoryboardSegue and specify the receiving class as in var declaration { var DestViewController: secondViewController = segue.destination as! secondViewController } ?

Comment: what I'm doing wrong? I just created a brand new  thirdViewController that is the exact copy of secondViewController and here's the code

Comment: `import UIKit

class thirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var thirdReceivedTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    var thirdLabelText = "ss"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         thirdReceivedTextLabel.text! = thirdLabelText
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    

   
}`

Comment: in the prepare(for:segue:sender) I just created a new variable pointing to the thirdViewController `var destViewController: thirdViewController = segue.destination as! thirdViewController
        destViewController.thirdLabelText = inputTextField.text!` but I get an "cannot assign a value of type tring to a type UILabel